# HTML5 Canvas Cannot load Kinetic.js

Tags: javascript, html, kineticjs

I am trying to use KineticJS in my JavaScript.

This line is in my index.html:

```
<script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v5.0.2.min.js"></script>
```

It returns *Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)*

I have installed KineticJS in a parent folder of the directory of index.html by doing:

```
npm install kinetic
```

in Git Bash.

**UPDATE**

I copied the kinetic folder manually to my index.html directory.
Now I'm doing this line in my index.html:

```
<script src="./kinetic/kinetic.js"></script>
```

However, I get a new error when executing the following code in javascript:

```
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
container: 'container',
width: 578,
height: 200
});
```

The error is this:

*Uncaught Can not find container in document with id containerkinetic.js:9252 Kinetic.Util.addMethods.setContainerkinetic.js:2803 Kinetic.Util.addMethods.setAttrskinetic.js:2312 Kinetic.Util.addMethods._initkinetic.js:132 Kinetic.Nodekinetic.js:7305 Kinetic.Util.addMethods.__initkinetic.js:277 Kinetic.Containerkinetic.js:9229 Kinetic.Util.addMethods.___initkinetic.js:315 Kinetic.Stagemain.js:13 (anonymous function)*

**UPDATE 2**

This is the part of the kinect.js code that throws the error:

```
setContainer: function(container) {
            if( typeof container === STRING) {
                var id = container;
                container = Kinetic.document.getElementById(container);
                if (!container) {
                    throw 'Can not find container in document with id ' + id;
                }
            }
            this._setAttr(CONTAINER, container);
            return this;
        },
```

Answer (score 3):

I forgot that I needed this line:

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

in my index.html

Otherwise "container" had no reference.